# How to fetch ftp transfer rate in java?

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am using FTPClient (apache commons net) to perform FTP Upload and Download. What is the best way to fetch transfer rate?

One way is to take start time before ftp.storeFile() and end time after ftp.storeFile() and use time difference and file size to get transfer rate. But it seems really naive and inefficient. What could be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The method you described seems problematics as you wont get a file transfer rate until the transfer is complete. You could consider using the technique you described above but instead only do partial file transfers (and get the transfer rate after each block) using either of the methods (from the FTPClient API):

`appendFile( String filename, InputStream dataToWrite);`

or

`appendFileStream( String filename );` this return an OutputStream to write to.

I have not done this myself but it seems like a better idea then just using the transfer rate estimated after the entire file has completed. It would drive me crazy if i had to wait for the transfer to complete to get transfer speed, but im an impatient person...

hope that helps